# Divide and Conquer Recursion

Tags: recursion, array-algorithms

I am just trying to understand how the recursion works in this example, and would appreciate it if somebody could break this down for me. I have the following algorithm which basically returns the maximum element in an array:

```
int MaximumElement(int array[], int index, int n)
    {  
        int maxval1, maxval2; 
        if ( n==1 ) return array[index];
        maxval1 = MaximumElement(array, index, n/2); 
        maxval2 = MaximumElement(array, index+(n/2), n-(n/2));
        if (maxval1 > maxval2)
            return maxval1;
        else
            return maxval2;
    }
```

I am not able to understand how the recursive calls work here. Does the first recursive call always get executed when the second call is being made? I really appreciate it if someone could please explain this to me. Many thanks!

Comment: This is c++ I presume?

Comment: No specific programming language. I am just trying to understand the concept behind this method/function/pseudocode. I have a Java background.

Comment: In Java you probably wouldn't use the `int n` parameter (but you could).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code comments embedded:

```
    // the names index and n are misleading, it would be better if we named it:
    // startIndex and rangeToCheck
int MaximumElement(int array[], int startIndex, int rangeToCheck)
{  
    int maxval1, maxval2; 

    // when the range to check is only one cell - return it as the maximum
    // that's the base-case of the recursion
    if ( rangeToCheck==1 ) return array[startIndex];
    // "divide" by checking the range between the index and the first "half" of the range
    System.out.println("index = "+startIndex+"; rangeToCheck/2 = " + rangeToCheck/2);
    maxval1 = MaximumElement(array, startIndex, rangeToCheck/2);
    // check the second "half" of the range
    System.out.println("index = "+startIndex+"; rangeToCheck-(rangeToCheck/2 = " + (rangeToCheck-(rangeToCheck/2)));
    maxval2 = MaximumElement(array, startIndex+(rangeToCheck/2), rangeToCheck-(rangeToCheck/2));

    // and now "Conquer" - compare the 2 "local maximums" that we got from the last step
    // and return the bigger one
    if (maxval1 > maxval2)
        return maxval1;
    else
        return maxval2;
 }
```

**Example of usage:**

```
int[] arr = {5,3,4,8,7,2};
int big = MaximumElement(arr,0,arr.length-1);
System.out.println("big = " + big);
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
index = 0; rangeToCheck/2 = 2
index = 0; rangeToCheck/2 = 1
index = 0; rangeToCheck-(rangeToCheck/2 = 1
index = 0; rangeToCheck-(rangeToCheck/2 = 3
index = 2; rangeToCheck/2 = 1
index = 2; rangeToCheck-(rangeToCheck/2 = 2
index = 3; rangeToCheck/2 = 1
index = 3; rangeToCheck-(rangeToCheck/2 = 1
big = 8
```

Comment: I understand the base case. I tried to understand the recursive calls, but I don't understand how it works. For e.g.: You have an array of size 6 (2,4,1,3,5,6). How do the recursive calls work? The first call is maxva1l = MaximumElement(array, 0, 6/2), and the second call becomes (maxval1 = MaximumElement(array, 0 ,3/2)?

Comment: I am sorry about! What I tried to ask was, how would that snippet work with an array of size 6 with values {2,4,1,3,5,6}? Thanks a lot!! That is: not how the output looks like, but how each step in the recursion calls works. Maybe, an array with a size of 4 might be easy to explain.

Comment: @acc_so I've added two debug printing (in Java) to the code above and updated the OUTPUT - maybe it'll give you a better idea in regards to the order of execution!

Comment: Still trying to understand it, but many thanks for responding!!

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that *both* recursive calls are being made, one after another. The first one searches have the array and returns the max, the second searches the other half and returns the max. Then the two maxes are compared and the bigger max is returned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What you have guessed is right. Out of the two recursive calls  `MaximumElement(array, index, n/2)` and `MaximumElement(array, index+(n/2), n-(n/2))`, the first call is repeatedly carried out until the call is made with a single element of the array. Then the two elements are compared and the largest is returned. Then this comparison process is continued until the largest element is returned.

Comment: That was how I initially understood it, but would return not terminate the program before all of the comparisons are made?

Comment: No. Return will only terminate one particular function call execution. The other functions calls will be carried out.

Comment: A little bit more detail please! :--) Could you please explain the recursion with a simple example? Something like an array with 4 values?